# Java fx intersects doesn't work

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx-8

I am working on a small platformer using javafx and My character is floating above the floor. I'm implementing the built in javafx method .intersects that check the boundaries of two rectangles to see if they overlap the setting the players vertical speed to zero. the part of the code I think is relevent is pasted her but the full program is at this address: https://github.com/metrogo10/finalProject if you want to look into it more thoroughly.

```
if(G.getP().intersects(f)||(G.getP().intersects(pf)))
                {
                    if(G.getP().getSpdY()>0)
                    {
                        G.getP().setSpdY(0);    
                    }
                    if(input.contains("SPACE")||input.contains("UP")||input.contains("W"))
                    {
                        G.getP().addVelocity(0, -560);
                    }
                }
                }
```

this is the code that is called by the first method.

```
 public boolean intersects(Sprite s)
{
    return s.getBoundary().intersects( this.getBoundary());
}
```

G.getP() is the player and f is the floor pl is a platform. The second if statement basically allows the player to "jump" (i'm still working on the numbers though). The character behaves as expected just about 30 px higher than it should be. like I said at the top the .intersects method is from the javafx library. btw I'm using jafafx8 and eclipse neon.

Comment: How do you know it isn['t working? What do you expect the result to be, and what do you actually get? And the relevant code is probably in the intersect() method. Also, why do you keep calling G.getP()? why not just write `Player p = G.getP()` and then use p for the rest - much less typing, and easier to read.

Comment: I expect it to be standing on the floor but it's floating above the floor instead. and I keep calling it that way because I want to keep my instance in one place so its easier to keep track of instead of having a duplicate instance that might get changed and then having to set the first one equal to the second.